# how to solve this div overlay problem in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

How to solve `div` overlay problem here I've one `div` in this `div` I've added two class `col-sm-6`. But when I am checking responsive it will going over of the `div`. I don't know how to solve. can anyone please help me.

I've attch the image of the output you can see :)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p><strong>Showing 1 to 6 of 6 entries</strong></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="top: -8px;">
      <div class="pagination">
        <button class="btn btn-link previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info number">1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-link next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have some custom css that's causing the problem.

Comment: you may need to add container class of bootstrap after <div class="row">, and then your col-sm-6 divs

Comment: Attached image is not very clear ? Please attach little bit clear image, it will be really helpful if you add working snippet of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have found mobile grid class (col-xs-12) missing. Please try below snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <p><strong>Showing 1 to 6 of 6 entries</strong></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="pagination">
                    <button class="btn btn-link previous">Previous</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info number">1</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link next">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the div "col-12" for mobile size in bootstrap4."col-sm-6" don't work for size less than 557px.and make your div's "float" right.

```css
.float-right{
  float:rigth !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 float-right">
      <p><strong>Showing 1 to 6 of 6 entries</strong></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 float-right" style="top: -8px;">
      <div class="pagination">
        <button class="btn btn-link previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info number">1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-link next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```